# can't find eosio.hpp on file-system

Tags: library

eosiocpp finds eosio.hpp(compile runs perfect), but I can't find eosio.hpp on file-system(using macOS)

[image]

[image]

Comment: How did you install `eos`? Have you tried searching from the root directory, i.e. `sudo find / -name eosio.hpp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to formulate a question, like:

"How to find eosio.hpp on the file-system?"

Now, the answer:

I recently used this here:

```
laz@laz-vb:~$ locate eosio.hpp
/home/laz/eos/contracts/eosiolib/eosio.hpp
```

To be sure its the filed that eosiocpp uses, just open it with an editor, then type some random chars in it. Using eosiocpp now should result in some errors.

Comment: As you can see from second picture, locate command returns two eosio.hpp
But only one exists....

Comment: This would be linux/unix specific. try

     sudo updatedb

see: https://superuser.com/questions/387638/a-file-shows-in-locate-command-but-dont-exist-why